# Efficient way to store a set of list of string in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I want to know which is the most efficient way to store a set of list of strings in C#.

#### Background

My goal is to store information about "properties" like `Hold(object)` or `Location(x,y,object)`. To do this I have a dictionary that map the property name to a "set of values".

For example, suppose I have a "location" set for the "location" property with these values

```
location -> ["1","2","robot1"]
            ["2","3","robot2"]
            ["2","5","key1"]
```

I want to perform query like

```
DB["location"].Contains(["1","2","robot1"])
```

I don't know if it is possible but it is to give you an idea of what I need. :)

#### What I have done

I have to modify and access these data frequently so I opted for an HashSet. But I have two main options:

1. The first is to use something like `HashSet<string[]>`. The problem is I think that HashSet cannot find duplicates because the standard behavior is to compare arrays by reference. For the same reason I don't know a good way to solve the "check if a [a,b,c] is contained in the set" problem.
2. The second is to use something like `HashSet<List<string>>`. But I don't need a List to store a simple set of tuple. It seems to me too much for a simple job like that.

An alternative is to write my own class to store "arguments" but I don't want to do this if something exists in the standard library. :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Make an `IEqualityComparer<string[]>`.

Comment: Is there a reason for why you would like to use strings, rather than just creating classes to represent these collection of properties?

Comment: @Porkbutts Because I will know the properties only at runtime. I parse property definition from a file (similar to [PDDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language) so I need something that can handle every possible definition. I'm using strings because I get them directly from the file.

Comment: Instead of having a `HashSet` of type `string[]`, why not create a class that encapsulates the `string[]` but overrides `HashCode/Equals` using, say, the concatenation of the strings (with some delimiter). That will provide you with the desired functionality I believe. E.g. Hashcode(`["1", "2", "robot1"]`) == Hashcode(`"1 2 robot1"`) or something similar. (I say use a delimiter so you don't have situations like `["1", "2robot1"] == ["1", "2", "robot1"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An alternative is to write my own class to store "arguments" but I don't want to do this if something exists in the standard library. :)

This would actually be my preference.  While it's a bit of work to write this up, having an actual type to hold the values provides the ability to build the equality directly into the type, and makes its usage very explicit.

In your case, you could store 2 ints and a string instead of 3 strings, etc.  More importantly, the `int` and `string` values can be named appropriately, which in turn makes your code far more readable and understandable.

Comment: This is the way I'm going. Unfortunately I have to "generalize" because I will know the properties type only at runtime (I parse them from a file).

Answer (score 1):

Use HashSet and Tuple might be a choice

```
HashSet<Tuple<int, int, string>> collections;
```

and if you prefer using all strings:

```
HashSet<Tuple<string, string, string>> collections;
```

And for equality of Tuple, you might find [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387109.aspx) useful. No matter which form you like, you can use below example as a reference:

```
Tuple<string, double, int>[] scores = 
                  { Tuple.Create("Ed", 78.8, 8),
                    Tuple.Create("Abbey", 92.1, 9), 
                    Tuple.Create("Ed", 71.2, 9),
                    Tuple.Create("Sam", 91.7, 8), 
                    Tuple.Create("Ed", 71.2, 5),
                    Tuple.Create("Penelope", 82.9, 8),
                    Tuple.Create("Ed", 71.2, 9),
                    Tuple.Create("Judith", 84.3, 9) };

  // Test each tuple object for equality with every other tuple. 
  for (int ctr = 0; ctr < scores.Length; ctr++)
  {
     var currentTuple = scores[ctr];
     for (int ctr2 = ctr + 1; ctr2 < scores.Length; ctr2++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}: {2}", currentTuple, scores[ctr2], 
                                            currentTuple.Equals(scores[ctr2]));      

     Console.WriteLine();
  }   
}
```